# How to copy some arguments from a command output(bash)?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to copy some arguments from my command. For example:

`last -1x shutdown` output will be `shutdown system down 5.10.17_1 Mon Jan 1 01:00 - 12:00 (11:00)`

How do I copy only the `11:00` to bash variable?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You write _copy some arguments_, but then you seem to ask how to parse the _output of a command_ to retrieve a piece of it. Please, clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the tags you used I guess you are limited to bash only. This should work in your specific case which consists in selecting the (only) part between parentheses:

```
v=$(last -1x shutdown)
v="${v#*\(}"
v="${v%*\)*}"
echo "$v"
11:00
```

Or, with recent enough bash versions (at least bash 3.0, if I remember well):

```
[[ $(last -1x shutdown) =~ .*\((.*)\) ]]
v="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "$v"
11:00
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
last -1x shutdown | sed -n '1s/.*(\(..:..\))/\1/p'
```